# How do I set a variable based on the specific struts action utilizing the JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, struts

I have a few "template" JSP files that are used in more than one struts action. I have another JSP file that I would like to set based on the particular action being called. For example:

```
<% if(this is one.action) { int testVar = 1; } %>
<% if(this is two.action) { int testVar = 2; } %>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: is it in struts2 or Struts2??

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be for both action files to implement a common method, lets say:

```
public Integer getPageID() {
    return pageID;
}
```

then in your JSP:

```
<s:if test="%{pageID == 0}">
  <s:set name="testVar" value="1"/>
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="%{pageID == 1}">
  <s:set name="testVar" value="2"/>
</s:elseif>
```

If you are only setting one variable then you should consider just using the variable direct from the action class.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with Struts 2**

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class MyLoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        String className = invocation.getAction().getClass().getName();
        System.out.println("Before calling action: " + className);
                    int pageNo = 0 ;
                    if(className.equals("Login")) {
                       pageNo = 1;
                    } else if(className.equals("Login")) {
                       pageNo = 2;
                    } // so on for other pages

                    String result = invocation.invoke();        
                    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext ();
                    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
                    request.setAttribute("pageNo", pageNo);
        return result;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroying ...");
    }
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initializing ...");
    }
}
```

Now in your whichever jsp page you want you will get request variable using

```
request.getAttribute("pageNo");
```

**Solution with Struts 1**

Instead of Interceptor use RequestProcessor to put pageNo variable in request scope

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor; 

public class CustomRequestProcessor extends RequestProcessor { 

public boolean processPreprocess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out .println("Called the preprocess method before processing the request");
        String path = processPath(request, response);
        if (path == null) {
           return;
        }
        int pageNo = 0 ;
        if(path.equals("Login")) {
            pageNo = 1;
        } else if(path.equals("Login")) {
            pageNo = 2;
        } // so on for other pages
        request.setAttribute("pageNo", pageNo);

        return super.processPreprocess(request,response);
    }
}
```